# Constructing a class from a line in a parameter file

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing

I've got a problem where I need to parse a line in a parameter file of the form

```
PotentialName [... variable number of parameters]
```

I've got code which works however it seems like it will be horrendous to maintain when I add more than a few options here.

What would be the best design pattern to avoid the long chain of else ifs and what looks like (to my eyes) quite a bit of boilerplate for each option I add.

```
std::shared_ptr<Potential> construct_potential( std::istringstream& iss )
{
    std::string pot_type;
    iss >> pot_type;

    if( pot_type == "NFW" ) {
        double rho0, rs;
        iss >> rho0 >> rs;
        return std::make_shared<NFW>(rho0, rs);
    }
    else if( pot_type == "MiyamotoNagai" ) {
        double m, a, b;
        if( iss >> m >> a >> b ) {
            return std::make_shared<MiyamotoNagai>(m, a, b);
        } else {
            throw ParseError("Expected 3 parameters for " + pot_type + " potential");
        }
    }
    else if( pot_type == "Kepler" ) {
        double m;
        if( iss >> m ) {
            return std::make_shared<Kepler>(m);
        } else {
            throw ParseError("Expected 1 parameter for " + pot_type + " potential");
        }
    }
    else {
        throw ParseError("Unknown Potential: " + pot_type);
    }
}
```

How can I improve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach to doing this is two-fold. Firstly, you'll want to modify your classes to have a constructor taking an `std::istringstream&` as an argument. The second part will be to make a map of strings to constructor functions. So let's assume our (skeleton) classes look something like:

```
class Potential
{
public:

    virtual ~Potential() { }

    virtual void print() const = 0;

};

class NFW
  : public Potential
{
private:

    double rho0;
    double rs;

public:

    NFW(std::istringstream& iss)
    {
        iss >> rho0 >> rs;
    }

    virtual ~NFW() = default;

    virtual void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << "NFW: rho0: " << rho0 << ", rs: " << rs << "\n";
    }
};

class MiyamotoNagai
  : public Potential
{
private:

    double m, a, b;

public:

    MiyamotoNagai(std::istringstream& iss)
    {
        iss >> m >> a >> b;
    }

    virtual ~MiyamotoNagai() = default;

    virtual void print() const override
    {
        std::cout << "MiyamotoNagai m: " << m << ", a: " << a 
                  << ", b: " << b << "\n";
    }
};
```

We then define the type our map will hold: it will hold a function that will return a `std::shared_ptr<Potential>`, and will take a `std::istringstream&` as an argument:

```
using function_t = std::function<std::shared_ptr<Potential>(std::istringstream&)>;
```

Using this, our map becomes:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, function_t> register_map;
```

To add to this, we just need some very simple lambda functions that forward to the corresponding constructor:

```
register_map["NFW"] = [](std::istringstream& iss) { return std::make_shared<NFW>(iss); };
register_map["MiyamotoNagai"] = [](std::istringstream& iss) { return std::make_shared<MiyamotoNagai>(iss); };
```

The function to actually create our `Potential` subclass then looks like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Potential> create_potential(std::istringstream& iss)
{
    std::string potential_type;
    iss >> potential_type;
    auto it = register_map.find(potential_type);
    if(it == register_map.end()) {
        throw ParseError("Unknown Potential " + potential_type);
    }
    return it->second(iss);
}
```

With this, each constructor will need to do its own checking and error handling (which I've omitted above). As written, this better adheres to the open-closed principle (code should be open for extension, closed for modification), as the only thing you should have to touch when you create another subclass is adding another call to `register_class[...]`.

A test example:

```
int main()
{
    register_map["NFW"] = [](std::istringstream& iss) { return std::make_shared<NFW>(iss); };
    register_map["MiyamotoNagai"] = [](std::istringstream& iss) { return std::make_shared<MiyamotoNagai>(iss); };
    std::istringstream iss("NFW 5 4");
    auto test = create_potential(iss);
    test->print();
}
```

As a final point, make absolutely sure this needs a `shared_ptr` over a `unique_ptr`. Without context it is impossible to tell, but you should always reach for `unique_ptr` first, and `shared_ptr` only if it is absolutely necessary; it may be in this case, but it is still something to very carefully think about.

Comment: Thank you, thats working perfectly. And you were right I didn't need a ``shared_ptr`` I only needed a ``unique_ptr`` which has increased the speed of my code to boot!

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use Factory Method pattern here:

- Define interface for construction of your Potential (i.e.
  `PotentialCreator`).
- Define concrete implementations for each supported potential (`KeplerPotentialCreator`, `MiyamotoNagaiPotentialCreator`, etc).
- Register pairs id-implementation in some entity, available during runtime.

Change your creator to something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<Potential> construct_potential( std::istringstream& iss ) {
    std::shared_ptr<PotentialCreator> concreteCreator = registry.get(iss);
    if(!concreteCreator) {
        throw ParseError("Unknown Potential: " + pot_type);
    }
    return concreteCreator->construct();
}
```